# Ambiguous Value Transfer Repeater By Session Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to transfer value from one page to another page from repeater button control click. 
OnLoad It transfer correct TID to next page but on button click Of “India” It gives wrong TID to next page.

Database scenario is:
Database Name “Test”
Table Name:”ConDet”

```
Table Structure:

TID     Location    CountryName

1001    Mumbai      India

1002    Delhi       India

1003    New York    USA

1004    Tokyo       Japan
```

Main Page Design:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <table><tr><td>
        <asp:Button ID="Ind"  runat="server" Text="India" OnClick="Ind_Click"/>
    </td><td>
        <asp:Button ID="usa"  runat="server" Text="USA"/>

    </td><td>
        <asp:Button ID="jap"  runat="server" Text="Japan"/>

    </td></tr></table>

    <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepeaterClick" >
        <ItemTemplate >
            <table><tr><td>
                <asp:Label ID="ConCode" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("TID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td><td>
                <asp:Label ID="loc" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("Location") %>'></asp:Label>

            </td><td>
                <asp:Label ID="Country" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("CountryName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td></tr><tr><td>
               <asp:Button ID="inpt" runat="server"  Text="Contect"  CommandName="contact" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
            </td></tr></table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>    
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBind();
    }

    public void DBind() 
    {
        string sqlconstr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mystring"];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlconstr);
        con.Open();

        string sql = "select * from ConDet order by TID desc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        rep.DataSource = ds;
        rep.DataBind();


    }

    protected void RepeaterClick(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "contact")
        {

            Label srk = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("ConCode");
            Session["PID"] = srk.Text;
            Server.Transfer("Test.aspx");

        }
    }

    protected void Ind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlconstr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mystring"];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlconstr);
        con.Open();

        string sql = "select * from ConDet where CountryName='India' order by TID desc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        rep.DataSource = ds;
        rep.DataBind();

    }
```

Next Page Name:Test Page

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="CCode" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CCode.Text = Session["PID"].ToString();
    }
```

I am trying to transfer TID to another page “Test”  on load event working well. It’s allow me to transfer Correct TID To next page “Test” but when I try to load fresh data on click button (text= “India”) sortwise it gives wrong TID to next page name “Test”
Where I am wrong?. How to Solve it to get correct TID transfer to next page on any order?.

Comment: why u are using session instead of you can use query string

Comment: Thanks Ganesh_Devlekar, here I just put one string transfer example actually there are more than three string I have to transfer on next page so is it safe by query string?. If yes than how?. And Important why it is transfer wrong data to next page?. it is important to know.

Comment: You can Encrypt your query string looks like this which can have more than one values `enc=o+Eq+ZR7wDJCSh4UjSOZ/wiaLLNkbGWBuCESqcnydXGEEssF1U+FLi7Bsk4Kx`

Comment: yes you can use encrypt and decrypt while using querry string

Comment: Ganesh_Devlekar and dazzling kumar fine but i want to know what's wrong with this code. why it's transfer wrong value?.

Comment: first of all use the **if(!isPostBack){  DBind();}**  in the page load event then see if there is nay change or not ?

Comment: yogi970, great it works, but can you explain it in details?.

Comment: put a break-point in the click event and see whether it give correct value @user2741987

Comment: Thanks Yogi it works and rest of guys thanks for your feedback

Comment: But it still remain unclear why it gives wrong ID if repeater databound on postback mode?.